# Swagger dependency not recognized by maven

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

i'm trying to add springfox/swagger to my spring boot app, however when added to pom file, versions of dependencies are not recognized by maven. Unfortunatley i couldn't find the reason behind it. Here fragment of my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Versions are marked red as not recognized by maven. What might be te reason behind such behavior?
I'm using maven 3.3.9.

Comment: I checked your dependencies using maven central. They seem to exist. Are you using an IDE? If yes which? Does the red marker come with any error message?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ, the error message says "Dependency xyz not found"

Comment: Did you configure a private maven repo? (either in your POM.xml or elsewhere?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These artifacts are present in Maven Repository so you should be able to add them as dependencies. There are three possible causes for this behaviour:

1. You have defined custom repositories in your `pom.xml`.
2. Your have a customized maven configuration in your IDE.
3. You have defined a custom list of repositories (it can happen if you use something like `Nexus` to provide libraries) in your `settings.xml` maven configuration file.

I've also checked the [Springfox Reference](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#maven), and you can directly add this custom repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
      <name>jcenter</name>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: adding custom repository solved my issue, i dont know what the root cause was but still. +1 for your answer